# Stop flex children wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container and the children in that are wrapping, I want them to both remain 100% in width - how would I do this?

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="container">sadasd</div>
  <div class="container">adasdsad</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shx2yheg/

Comment: First, it is `nowrap` without a hyphen (which is the default so you can omit it), second, you say _the children in that are wrapping_, but they aren't wrapping, so it would be good it you could be more clear with what you mean.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to set `flex: 0 0 100%` on flex child elements and initial value of `flex-wrap` is `nowrap` so you don't have to change that.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.container {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  border: blue 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="container">sadasd</div>
  <div class="container">adasdsad</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do that by setting the `flex-flow` property on the the flexbox like this

```
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-flow: column;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
}
```